# Aggregate data from several polygons into one in QGIS

Tags: qgis, census, average, aggregate

I am using QGIS 3.10.1, and I am trying to aggregate Census data (polygons) according to another set of polygons (neighbourhood areas that I have drawn). While I am able to clip the Census data to each neighbourhood, the census data polygon boundaries still show within the neighbourhood polygons, and is still separate data.

Does anyone know how I can take all the census polygon data within a neighbourhood boundary and combine it in to **one dataset showing averages / sum etc?**

Comment: A screenshot showing the spatial relation of neighourhoods and census data would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need is to do a Spatial Join.

In QGIS you can do it by searching the tool *Join attributes by location*. There you can select the different layers and specify the statistics you wanna do.

Comment: Thank you for this! I had read about that function but didn't quite trust it to do what I wanted... but having tried it out it seems that it does! I appreciate your input as it's good to know the right tool to use! :)